Limit at infinity of complex logarithm function
For a complex function$f\left( z\right) $ and a complex number $L\in \mathbb{C} $, we have
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty }f\left( z\right) =L\Leftrightarrow \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f\left( \frac{1}{z}\right) =L
$$
and$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty }f\left( z\right) =\infty \Leftrightarrow \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{f\left( \frac{1}{z}\right) }=0.
$$
Let $f\left( z\right) =\ln \left( z\right) $ be a complex logarithm function. Then we have
\begin{align}
&f\left( \frac{1}{z}\right)\\
=&\ln \left( \frac{1}{z}\right)\\
=& \ln \left( \left\vert \frac{1}{z}\right\vert \right) +i\mathrm{Arg}\left( \frac{1}{z}\right)\\
=& -\ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) -i\mathrm{Arg}\left( z\right) .
\end{align}
The real part $-\ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) $ diverges as $z\rightarrow 0$, therefore $f\left( \frac{1}{z}\right) $ does not convergeto any complex number as $z\rightarrow 0$. So we can conclude that $f\left(z\right) $ does not converge to any complex number as $z\rightarrow \infty $.
Now I want to check if $f\left( z\right) $ diverges to infinity as $z\rightarrow \infty $. We have
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{f\left( \frac{1}{z}\right) }\\
&=\frac{1}{\ln \left( \frac{1}{z}\right) } \\
&=\frac{1}{\ln \left( \left\vert \frac{1}{z}\right\vert \right) +i\mathrm{Arg}\left( \frac{1}{z}\right) } \\
&=\frac{1}{-\ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) -i\mathrm{Arg}\left( z\right) } \\
&=\frac{-\ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) +i\mathrm{Arg}\left( z\right) }{\left[ -\ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) -i\mathrm{Arg}\left( z\right) \right] \left[ -\ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) +i\mathrm{Arg}\left( z\right) \right] } \\
&=\frac{-\ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) +i\mathrm{Arg}\left( z\right) }{\left[ \ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) \right] ^{2}+\left[ \mathrm{Arg}\left( z\right) \right] ^{2}} \\
&=-\frac{\ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) }{\left[ \ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) \right] ^{2}+\left[ \mathrm{Arg}\left( z\right) \right] ^{2}}+i\frac{\mathrm{Arg}\left( z\right) }{\left[ \ln \left( \left\vert z\right\vert \right) \right] ^{2}+\left[ \mathrm{Arg}\left( z\right) \right] ^{2}}.
\end{align}
This is where I'm stuck. I guess that both real and imaginary part do not
converge to zero as $z\rightarrow 0$. But I cannot prove it.

$\left| {\ln z} \right| \ge {\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} (\ln z) = \ln \left| z \right| \to  + \infty $ as $z\to\infty$.

I really appreciate your help. I never thought of that!
